# Combine Multiple Content Types and View

Tags: views, nodes

I have need to create a page with following information.
Personal Information,
Address and 
Contract Information.

One Personal Information will have multiple address and multiple Contract information. I am thinking of creating three content types. The personal information page will have add address and add contract buttons which will popup the respective content type. When the address or contract popup is closed then control is passed to the Personal Information page, here I should be able to view the contact and address information just added in tabular format. I thought it may be a view.

My question is, Is it possible to achieve this kind of work in Drupal 7? If yes how can I do it. It will be nice to have some information so that I can look into the right direction. Some example sites would be help full.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new content types. You can create fields and use [FieldCollection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module to group as many field as you like.

and show (Display) it using [FieldCollection Views](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection_views) module.

Find demo here,

[FieldCollection Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOSjYsphZ6Q)

[FieldCollection Views  Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GlfYhsk3X0)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am looking at the demo and will try. If I have some additional problems then I will just put it here

Comment: I just view the presentation. My basic requirement is like this. I have the content type Personal Information. This page should also have a view of the Location content type as show in the demo in the same place where I enter the personal information content, not while viewing personal information.